# How to restrict access to a specific node to to an individual user

Tags: nodes

I am trying to see if I can put together a D9 site for this person how designs custom 3D images and animations. I'm working on a way to have him sell the files once completed, but first I need a way for him to preview the file for the client while he's working on it. For this to work, I need a way to restrict viewing of the node/image so only the logged in client can see it.I looked at the modules that I thought might work, and so far only Taxonomy Access Control comes close, but I'm not sure if it does what I need. Does anybody have any ideas what might be what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively easy way to do this without writing code.

Assumptions

- There is one designer who has multiple clients.
- The designer should have access to everything, while each client should only have access to that client's designs from the designer.

How to implement

- Give the designer all content administrator permissions. This will let the designer create, update, and delete content as needed.
- Create a custom content type and name it however you like (for this example, we'll call it **Designs**).
- Set up accounts for clients with the authenticated role.
- Give the authenticated role permission to "view own content" for the **Designs** content type.  Do not give authenticated users the permission to edit or delete **Designs** content (or, more broadly, all of their own content).
- When the designer creates a **Design** node for a client, in the admin UI, assign the client as the author of the node.

Because the client is the node author, they will be able to view the content (since it is their own content, because they are assigned as the author) but nothing else (based on the permissions configured above).

Comment: That sounds a lot easier than what I tried. I installed Node Access module and set it up similar to how you described. I'm not sure which would work the best in the long run, but you way sounds much less complicated.